# How to get git to display the most recent n commits from all local branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-log

I would like to see the most recent n commits (generally 1 or 2) for all local branches in my respository.

I have tried "git log -1 --all" and "git log -1 --branches" but this doesn't have the effect I expect in git 1.8.4.

Basically I would like the equivalent of

```
for i in $(ls .git/refs/heads/); do echo ====$i====; git log -1 $i; done
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you already have?

Comment: Why don't you make an alias out of it?

Comment: If by "active branches" you mean "those whose refs have not been moved to packed-refs or have been updated since then", the above is more or less the way to go.  You might want to add something to handle branch names with embedded slashes though.

Comment: @chris : The existing solution relies on me being the root folder of the repository.  I'd like a way to do it from anywhere.  Also, if I use the native git tools I can pass other command line arguments to get more powerfull functionality.  If I try to write a script that accomplishes all that it quickly gets complex, and my time is better spent learning how to use what is already available (assuming something exists).

Comment: @torek  Did I ask about "active branches"?  I intended to ask about "local branches" which is a well defined git term with a unique meaning.  The text of the question says "local branches", and I don't think there have been any edits, so I'm not sure where you get "active branches" from.    Local branches are those which are in the .git/refs/heads folder, which is why my bash solution works.  See my reponse to chris as to why I am unhappy with my solution.

Comment: @Spacemoose: it's in the title of the question (which got stuck in my head so that I didn't see "local branches" at that point).

Comment: @Chris It does not work at all if there is a slash in the name of the branch.

Answer (score 4):

Edit, Aug 2018: here's a quick short-cut in case you only want to look at *one* commit from each branch tip:

```
git log --no-walk --branches
```

The way this works is that `--no-walk` prevents `git log` from looking at any commits that are *not* named on the command line, while `--branches` names, on the command line, every branch-tip commit.

(The `--branches`, `--tags`, and `--remotes` options all take optional glob patterns as well, so you can look at all `m*` commits with `git log --no-walk --branches='m*'` for instance.)

---

Local (i.e., "not remote") branches are those whose reference-name starts with `refs/heads/`.

The `git for-each-ref` command is designed to iterate over reference-names, so it's usually the thing to use:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

will print them all out.  Note that you can't just pass this to `git log -1` though, as that will stop after logging one commit from the first reference; so you need something like what you did.  There are a bunch of ways to construct this, e.g.:

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
    while read branch; do git log -1 $branch; done
```

or:

```
git for-each-ref --format='git log -1 %(refname:short)' refs/heads | sh
```

In the second case you should add `--shell` to make sure that all expansions are quoted.  This protects against, e.g., a branch named `foo$bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a list with every branch and their last commit can be achieved by using:

`git branch -vv`

If you want something more detailed, or a variable number of commits to go back to, your own solution is pretty good already. You can create a git alias for it by adding the following to ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias]                                                                         
    log-all-branches = "!sh -c 'git_dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/refs/heads/"; for i in $(ls $git_dir); do echo ====$i====; git log -n $1 $i; done' -"
```

Now you can get the last 2 commits for each branch by executing `git log-all-branches 2`

Comment: This is a good start, but the OP's point about having to be in the root directory is a good one. You may want to incorporate `git rev-parse --git-dir`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. After OP specified this in the comments to his question I have adapted the command in my answer to that.